# Given a finite sample space S find the probability an event is the subset of another

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I was simply trying to rationalize this in a thought process. My professor said to think about it for an upcoming class but I don't really know where to start. What we have is a finite sample space $S$ with $N$ sample points. We then randomly sample two subests $A$ and $B$ that are independent and want to arrive at what $P(A \subset B)$ is. Any help is much appreciated, mostly intuitive help is requested but a concise argument is also welcome if possible. Thank you!

Comment: Select each element at random from N with prob half independently, and generate a subset A and another B in the same process. What is the probability that B contains all elements of A. Assume that you selected k out of N elements in set A. Probability of B being a superset conditioned on this event is $2^{N-k}/2^{N}$ (Yes?) - Prob of set A containing k elements is C(n,k)/2^k.. and so on..

Answer (score 6):

We assume that all subsets $A$ and $B$ are equally likely, and that the choices are independent.

Stop in front of each of the $N$ points, and decide whether to put it (i) in $A$ and $B$; (ii) in $A$ but not in $B$; (iii) not in $A$ but in $B$; (iv) not in $A$ and not in $B$. At any of the $N$ points, these $4$ choices are equally likely.

We get $A\subseteq B$ if and only if at **each** of the $N$ points we do one of (1), (iii), or (iv).   The required probability is therefore $\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^N$.

**Remark:** A possible (but less likely) interpretation of the notation used is that we want $A$ to be a *proper* subset of $B$. The probability that $A$ and $B$ are the same is $\frac{1}{2^N}$, which we subtract from $\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^N$.

Comment: That is very nice!

Comment: Andre Nicolas, that makes perfect sense! Thank you so much. However, your final remark confused me as if you take that difference we get $(\frac{1}{4})^N$ which is different from the $(\frac{3}{4})^N$ from your first explanation. I'm not sure if the second is the way to go but the first seems quite feasible.

Comment: I am confused.If suppose the set X is {1,2,3,4,5} and A is {1,2} and B is {2,3,4} then if we choose the element 5 then it neither lies in A and B but it doesn't also imply that A is a subset of B(as per the fourth case).

Comment: Also, would Venn Diagrams be helpful in this case?

Comment: @KaranSingh: You are right about a Venn diagram. In general the sets $A$ and $B$ divide the sample space (universal set) $S$ into $4$ parts. These are the $4$ choices described in words in the second paragraph.  About your earlier comment, the object $5$ is not the issue, the problem with your $A$ and $B$ is that when thinking about the number $1$, we did (ii), which is not allowed.

Comment: Do you mean to say that the object 5 will not be a part of the probability expression you calculated?

Comment: It will be part of the probability calculation.