# Find the probability that $A$ is a subset of $B$

Tags: probability

> Let $S$ be a set with n elements. Out of the $2^n$
>   subsets of $S$ two sets $A$ and $B$ are
>   randomly chosen with replacement.
>
> 1. What is the probability that $A$ contains $k$ elements?
> 2. Use the previous part to find the probability that $A$ is a subset of $B$.

I solved the question by counting all the possibilities that $A$ is a subset of $B$. The answer is $\frac{3^n}{4^n}$.

I should have solved it using conditional probability. The first step I was trying to do is to understand what are the 2 events $X$ and $Y$ which will help me by doing the following:

$ P(X|Y)= $ the probability that $A$ is a subset of $B$.

To describe the events $X$ and $Y$, I was expecting that the question will tell me that $Y$ happened, but the question **only** mention that $A$ and $B$ had been picked.

My questions:

1. How does this information help me describe the events $X$ and $Y$?
2. **Maybe it's a problem with my approach when I'm trying to solve a question using conditional probability?**

---

## Don't give me the answer.

Comment: Just curious, how did you arrive at $\frac{3^n}{4^n}$?  Conditioning on $|A|=k$, as the question's wording seems to REQUIRE you to do, does not seem like a very smart way to solve this problem.

Comment: I didn't your point. Maybe it's my English. I solved it in the same way as @Mike did but I didn't call it "The law of total probability". Also, I did the opposite: for every size of **$B$**, I checked in how many ways, $A\subseteq B$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Given a finite sample space S find the probability an event is the subset of another](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518063/given-a-finite-sample-space-s-find-the-probability-an-event-is-the-subset-of-ano)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do want to use conditional probability. Use the law of total probability to divide up the event $\{A\subseteq B\}$ based on the number of elements $A$ has:

$$P(A\subseteq B) = \sum_{k=0}^nP(A\subseteq B\,\,|\,\,|A|=k)\cdot P(|A|=k)$$

You've found $P(|A|=k)$, now you just need $P(A\subseteq B\,\,|\,\,|A|=k)$.

Answer (score 1):

Although the wording seems to REQUIRE conditioning on $|A|=k$, this seems to me like a tedious way.  Here's an alternate approach (that would not satisfy the original wording):

Consider any element $x \in S$.  Then:

- $P(x \in A) = P(x \in B) = 1/2$
- $P(x \in B \text{  or  } x \notin A) = 3/4$
- $A \subset B \ \ \text{  iff  }\ \  \forall x \in S: x \in B$ or $x \notin A$
- $P(A \subset B) = P(\forall x \in S: x \in B \text{ or } x \notin A) = \Pi_{x\in S} P(x \in B \text{  or  } x \notin A) = \big(\frac{3}{4}\big)^n$

The change from $\forall$ to $\Pi$ is allowed because the way we choose $A$ and $B$ means each $x$ is independent.