# Elegant Solution to Random Subsets

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have this question:

> Subsets A and B are chosen at random from a set X of cardinality 5. What is the probability that A is a subset of B?

I have got the right answer with this straightforward but monstrosity of an answer:

$\frac{1}{32}+\frac{5}{32}\left(\frac{5}{32}\cdot\frac{\operatorname{nCr}\left(4,4\right)}{\operatorname{nCr}\left(5,4\right)}+\frac{10}{32}\cdot\frac{\operatorname{nCr}\left(4,3\right)}{\operatorname{nCr}\left(5,3\right)}+\frac{10}{32}\cdot\frac{\operatorname{nCr}\left(4,2\right)}{\operatorname{nCr}\left(5,2\right)}+\frac{5}{32}\cdot\frac{\operatorname{nCr}\left(4,1\right)}{\operatorname{nCr}\left(5,1\right)}+\frac{1}{32}\right)+\frac{10}{32}\left(\frac{10}{32}\cdot\frac{\operatorname{nCr}\left(3,3\right)}{\operatorname{nCr}\left(5,3\right)}+\frac{10}{32}\cdot\frac{\operatorname{nCr}\left(3,2\right)}{\operatorname{nCr}\left(5,2\right)}+\frac{5}{32}\cdot\frac{\operatorname{nCr}\left(3,1\right)}{\operatorname{nCr}\left(5,1\right)}+\frac{1}{32}\right)+\frac{10}{32}\left(\frac{10}{32}\cdot\frac{\operatorname{nCr}\left(2,2\right)}{\operatorname{nCr}\left(5,2\right)}+\frac{5}{32}\cdot\frac{\operatorname{nCr}\left(2,1\right)}{\operatorname{nCr}\left(5,1\right)}+\frac{1}{32}\right)+\frac{5}{32}\left(\frac{5}{32}\cdot\frac{\operatorname{nCr}\left(1,1\right)} {\operatorname{nCr}\left(5,1\right)}+\frac{1}{32}\right)+\frac{1}{32}$

Is there a more elegant way to solve this? Please help me see it.

Comment: Yet an older duplicate: [Given a finite sample space S find the probability an event is the subset of another](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518063), found [using Approach$0$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24P(A%5Csubset%20B)%24&p=1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each element $x$ of $X$, note that the four following possibilities are equally likely:

- $x\notin A, x\notin B$
- $x\in A,x\notin B$
- $x\notin A,x\in B$
- $x\in A,x\in B$

For $A$ to be a subset of $B$, that would mean that for each of the elements $x$ you must have it be one of the first, third, or fourth cases and not the second case.

The probability is then $\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^5$

Comment: It was [a multiduplicate.](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=Probability+A+is+a+subset+of+B)